# Windows 8 Installation Fails

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, freeze

I have the Windows 8 32-bit ISO which fails to install when booted from a USB flash drive. It copies the files, the boot loader installs, but the install hangs when I boot into Windows 8 for the first time--it simply keeps on spinning forever.

The Windows 8 Release Preview does not work either. I did a VHD install of Windows 8 Developer Preview and it installed fine.

Looking at the partition from Windows 7, I can see that the files are present. What could be the problem?

Comment: you should give it more time. Sometimes you never know - it may be working in the background, but you assumed it's hung and cancelled it.

Comment: I actually tried trice man, it ran for 20 mins each time

Comment: @HackToHell which tool you used to make flash drive bootable? May be the tool has defect regarding Windows 8. Try to make it bootable through YUMI which support the Windows 8 bootable flash drive.

Comment: Or use MS' own USB/DVD Download Tool.

Comment: I used MS' own USB/DVD Download Tool.

Comment: Try Rufus -> http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: On which machine did you make the bootable disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unbelievable reason, the 64 bit version of Windows 8 installs properly !

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me by check updates of my materials composants and check "Update" when the Upgrade utility prompt me.

Hope it help you

Don't forget to uninstall all programs not updated for Win 8 before launching the update (like Comodo Internet Security, Adobe CS5 suite...)